# All events from Sharepoint calendar using webservice

Tags: .net, sharepoint, caml

I'm trying to get all list item in a calendar scheduled within 30 day of a given date.

```
            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>";
            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml += "<CalendarDate>" + calendarDate + "</CalendarDate>";
            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml += "<ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\" />";

            ndQuery.InnerXml = @"<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=""EventDate"" /><FieldRef Name=""EndDate"" /><FieldRef Name=""RecurrenceID"" /><Value Type=""DateTime""><Now /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=""EventDate"" /></OrderBy>";
```

Then I massage the data to get the data within the date range.

It seems to work if the given date is within a particular range. For example, I have an event for every Wednesday and Friday. if now is 6/5/2013, it returns data from now till 9/13/2013. Any query (for the given date) other than those two days (an earlier date like 4/5/2013 or a later date like 10/1/2014) returns no events between the date range.

**Update:** I changed the `<Value Type=""DateTime""><Year /></Value>` from `<Now />`, result is better that it does return some historical data, but not to previous year, nor to next year.

**Update:** I followed Douglas's suggestion, it missed the DateRangesOverlap part, so it only returns one node for the recurrent event instead of unfolded them. So I don't think it works.

**Update:** I found an article explaining the value type for the DateRangesOverlap. [Here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Use-SPServices-to-Get-Recurring-Events-as-Distinct-Items.aspx) confirms that `<Year />` only returns data from today and does not work with calendar date (the start date I wanted it to be). According to that article, `<Month />` is more reliable. So I can't do a date range search (at least not within a single web service call). I will use `<Month />` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try the following query string:

```
<Where><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>...</Value></Leq><Geq><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>...</Value></Geq></And></Where>
```

and specify the value of start date and end date with format like this `2013-06-01T00:00:00`.

Comment: I put `String ndQueryString = String.Format(@"<Where><And><Leq><FieldRef Name=""EventDate"" /><Value Type=""DateTime"">{0}</Value></Leq><Geq><FieldRef Name=""EndDate"" /><Value Type=""DateTime"">{1}</Value></Geq></And></Where>", startDay, lastDay);` where startDay and last Day are DateTime fields. It returns nothing.

Comment: Correction, I changed the startDay and lastDay with the format you mentioned above, it started to getting data, but it treated everyday having events for recurrent events. I guess I need to change my method of massaging those data.

Comment: Hi Douglas, I don't think this works since it misses the `<DateRangesOverlap>...</DateRangesOverlap> so it is not doing the unfolding of the recurrent events.

Comment: Have you added Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"?